# How to upload JFrame (java swing) window to an HTML page

Tags: java, html, swing, jframe, java-web-start

Do we have any tag in HTML for uploading JFrame window. I am aware of embedding a appletviewer in HTML using  tag. Do we have an alternative tag for the JFrame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't such html tag.

You can start a Swing application as an applet or using JNLP.